# Retrieve timestamp from Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, model-view-controller

I have a Java MVC model.Which has timestamp as one of the DB value which is already inserted into DB.I have declared the data type as Timestamp in DB,Now the problem is If i try to retrieve it is showing null values & can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp

Statement :

```
pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT timestamp, FROM nid where id=?");
pstmt.setDouble(1, nidev);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery(); 
        if(rs.next())
        {  
            timeBean.setHbtimestamp(rs.getTimestamp("timestamp"));

        }
```

Bean Class:

```
private Timestamp hbtimestamp;

public Timestamp getHbtimestamp() {
return hbtimestamp;
}
public void setHbtimestamp(Timestamp hbtimestamp) {
this.hbtimestamp = hbtimestamp;
}
```

**MyDB value is successfully inserted :2015-05-15 13:54:53**

**output: Value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp**

Comment: Timestamp is a reserved word. Can you just try to rename it to like LastModifiedDateTime? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Its stilll the same error

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `,` so it looks like this

```
SELECT `timestamp` FROM nid where id=?
```

Comment: Try wrapping the timestamp column with `

Comment: Sorry i didnt get you..can you please edit in above code

Comment: Is it the value of `timeBean.setHbtimestamp` that is 0000-00?

Comment: Maybe you can write out the value before you pass it to the function. Can you write out the `rs.getTimestamp("timestamp")` before `timeBean.setHbtimestamp`

Comment: Can you confirm that `rs.getTimestamp("timestamp")` has the correct value? If so, its most likley the `setHbtimestamp ` function that fails.

Comment: did you try and print out the database value before you pass it?

Comment: What for action is this? `pstmt.setDouble(1, nidev);` Im not familiar with Java. Can you do a count of the `rs` to also confirm that there is a row?